# SQL filtering on count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Much appreciation for anyone who can help or even tries.

So I have a table, GameHub, for each game 1 record indicates a person who played the game.
Game Hub :

```
Game ID Person
    33  1234
    34  1234
    38  1234
    38  1235
    33  1235
```

So 2 people played game 33 and 38, only 1 played game 34.

I've been struggling to find a SQL that will grab only the gameids where atleast 2 people have played.

The best I have (which does not work) would be :

```
SELECT GameHub.gameid FROM 'GameHub' HAVING COUNT(GameHub.personid) > 1
```

Sadly as simple as this sounds, I just cant crack it. Anyone seeing my mistake?

Thanks,
Tom.

- Update -

Changed the :

```
SELECT GameHub.gameid FROM GameHub HAVING COUNT(GameHub.personid) > 1
```

But only "33" gets returned, how can I get 33 and 38?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Group by`, which will tell you to group the result according to `GameHub.gameid`

```
SELECT GameHub.gameid 
FROM 'GameHub' 
GROUP BY GameHub.gameid
HAVING COUNT(GameHub.personid) > 1
```

**Update**
If this is your actual sql, try to add the column you added in `Group by`

```
SELECT GameHub.gameid, 
       GameMeta.gamedate 
FROM GameHub JOIN GameMeta 
 ON GameHub.gameid = GameMeta.gameid 
GROUP BY GameHub.gameid, GameMeta.gamedate 
HAVING COUNT( GameHub.personid ) >1;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of grouping by `Person`?

Comment: That was so fast it wont let me accept the answer! thanks alot Charles.

Comment: Hey Charles up for a bonus? I need to inner join this result to another table, any thoughts?

Comment: nvm even I got this one, my problem was I was trying to join after the result, but I inserted into there between From and Group :                                             SELECT GameHub.gameid, GameMeta.gamedate
FROM GameHub
JOIN GameMeta ON GameHub.gameid = GameMeta.gameid
GROUP BY GameHub.gameid
HAVING COUNT( GameHub.personid ) >1